# Download File with loopback 4

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, loopback4

I want to download a file from a loopback 4 based server. My current situation is, that i can access the file with fs.readFileSync, but it's only working for text-files. If i want to download pdf or zip files it's not working.

This is what i have so far:

```js
export class FileController
{
    constructor(
        @repository(FileRepository) public fileRepository: FileRepository
    ){}


    @get('/files/download/{id}')
    async download(@param.path.number('id') id: number): Promise<string>
    {
        const file = await this.fileRepository.findById(id);
        const filepath = file.FilePath;

        if(!fs.existsSync(filepath))
        {
            throw new HttpErrors.NotFound(`The File #${id} can not be delivered, because the file is missing.`);
        }
        else
        {
            // @todo set headers for content type, length and caching
            return fs.readFileSync(filepath,'utf8');
        }
    }
}
```

If i inject `RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE` into the constructor, I'm able to access the response object and might edit the headers using the `setHeader`-Method, but with no affect.

What do i have to do to:

1. pass the file content correctly to the client
2. set the headers to tell the browser the correct file meta data

Comment: `const file = await this.fileRepository.findById(id);`, what is the type of `file`?

Comment: I also change `fs.readFileSync(filepath,'utf8');` to `fs.readFileSync(filepath);` and it worked for me, i can download `.pdf` file.

Comment: @ZhikaiXiong file is just an object based on a database model representing metadata about the physical file. It contains the path, filetype, name etc.

Comment: @ZhikaiXiongi i changed the readFileSync as you suggested. It seems now its delivering the real content, but without setting an header for the content-type and filename. I only get the plain body. I have to add the file extension manually to be able to use the file. This is what i got and a peak into the database model: https://imgur.com/a/btnHKv3 How do i set the headers properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `this.response.download()`:

```js
return await new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {

    // your logic ...

    this.response.download(filepath, (err: any) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. i just replaced ```.download()``` by ```.sendFile()``` and ```.setHeader()```. The Download method always sets the Cotent-Disposition to attachment. If i want to download an image i need the inline mode. Now it works like a charm!